# Is it possible to transfer money from UK bank account to Egypt bank account?

Tags: united-kingdom, money-transfer, international-transfer, wire-transfer, egypt

I am working currently in UK and my HSBC uk bank told me that it is not possible to transfer from/to egypt any money, so is that really true? and what other ways I can do so?

Comment: If the bank says no, you cannot do anything. Ask them the reason. Try using a third party service provider or try a different bank.

Answer (score 2):

There are restrictions on transferring money OUT OF Egypt (although less tight than previously: http://www.aawsat.net/2014/01/article55326839 ) but there aren't any such restrictions on sending money INTO Egypt.

If you go to HSBC's retail UK banking pages and locate the page for International Money Transfers, http://www.hsbc.co.uk/1/2/international-money-transfer you can see that you can transfer up to £50,000 per day into Egypt via online banking, £10,000 via telephone banking, or unlimited by visiting the branch.

I'm not sure exactly what question you asked them or exactly what they said to you in response, but it sounds like there was some misunderstanding along the way.

Comment: I asked them that i want to transfer some money from my account to an egypt bank account, and they told me that this is not possible for some countries like egypt, but i saw their website and didn't find these info, so thats why i am asking

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment but could you not get an account with the National Bank of Egypt which has branches in the UK?